# Recursive JSON String Parser

Tags: javascript, json, recursion

I need help in parsing a JSON string and can't quite troubleshoot what is going wrong.

```
value = 0;

function calc(string) {
    let x = JSON.parse(string);
    var y;


    if (x.expr != undefined){
         y = JSON.stringify(x.expr);
    }
    else {
         y = x;
    }
    if (y.op == 'add') {
        return value = value + y.number;
    }
    else if (y.op == 'subtract') {
        return value = value - y.number;
    }
    x.expr = y;
    calc(y);

};

//console.log(calc('{"op" : "add", "number" : 5}' )); //expected value 5
//console.log(calc('{"op" : "subtract", "number" : 2}' )); //expected value 3
//console.log(calc('{"op" : "add", "number" : 19}' )); //expected value 22
console.log(calc('{"op": "subtract", "expr" : {"op" : "add", "number" : 15}}' )); //expected value 0
//console.log(calc('{"op": "add", "expr" : {"op" : "add", "expr" : {"op" : "subtract", "number" : 3}}}' )); //expected value 0
```

I have uncommented the portion that I am trying to debug. I am not very good with recursion and I'm trying to read in the JSON strings to calculate a number.

The embedded expressions are something new to me so I'm not sure how to proceed, i.e. what is the base case?

Please help me!

Comment: At the end of your function, you should return the result of calc()

Comment: Hint: Usually you'll have an outer set of code (another function?) that sets up for the recursion.  In particular, having JSON.parse() in the recursive function seems wrong.  And if you take it out, you won't have to JSON.stringify().  Then you can just worry about the data in your recursive function.

Comment: Hint 2: Every path of calc() should return a value.

Comment: Hint X: `expr` isn't a string and does not need to be parsed as JSON again. In fact, JSON seems to be a superfluous red herring here and should be omitted entirely. I see no reason why `calc` should have to deal with JSON in any way at all.

Comment: what are the expected values of last two expressions?

Comment: what's `{"op": "subtract", "expr" : {"op" : "add", "number" : 15}}` supposed to mean as a math equation? `value - (??? + 15)` there's something missing. Or `{"op": "add", "expr" : {"op" : "add", "expr" : {"op" : "subtract", "number" : 3}}}` -> `value + (??? + (??? - 3))`

Comment: The last two should evaluate to 0.

Comment: I don't understand how you get from `22` to `0` just adding/subtracting the numbers `15` and `3`

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear, when you run it with the commented out lines it should equal 37 {{"op" : "add", "number" : 15}}'. Then {"op": "subtract", "expr" : ... will subtract 37.  The firth line will result in double the value not 0.

Answer (score 0):

The [`JSON.parse` reviver parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Examples) can be used to traverse all values in [reverse level order](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reverse-level-order-traversal/) :

```js
var value = 0;

function calc(string) {
    var number;

    JSON.parse(string, function(key, val) {
        if (val.op) { 
            if ('number' in val)
                number = val.number;

            if (val.op === 'add')
                console.log(value, '+', number, '=', value += number, '\t', JSON.stringify(val));
            else
                console.log(value, '-', number, '=', value -= number, '\t', JSON.stringify(val));
        }
        return val;
    });
};

calc( '{"op": "subtract", "expr" : {"op" : "add", "number" : 15}}' );
calc( '{"op": "add", "expr" : {"op" : "add", "expr" : {"op" : "subtract", "number" : 3}}}' );
```